# Python readline output always makes blank space between the text that is printed

Tags: python

i have been learning Python for a few days now(Never learned programming before), and i am reading Learn Python The Hard Way. I am currently at excercise16 and i was experimenting little with it but i need little help. When i execute the script and write all three lines that are being asked for, then it reads first two lines that are inputted there is blank space between them when it reads lines. This is the script:

```
from sys import argv

script ,  filename= argv

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")  # first input
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")  # second input
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")  # third input

print "I'm going to write them down and read them later."

target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3)

target.close()

krc = open(filename , "r")
print "Reading the lines now \n%s \n%s" % (krc.readline() , krc.readline())
```

Output looks like this:

```
Reading the lines now
line1
    #<<<< Why is this blank space here?#
line2
```

I hope you understand my question(its probably some stupid mistake that i am missing). Thank you.

Comment: How are you running your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` inserts a new line. You have one before each of the variables in the string you print at the end. There is already a `\n` at the end of each line in the file so it's going to print an extra line in between them.

Comment: Thanks for help.I removed \n and it prints out properly now.

Answer (score 0):

`readline` doesn't remove the newline at the end of a line. You don't need to stick additional newline characters into the format string.